# How do i import SerialBlob?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

```java
// Initialise database
db = new MyDBHandler(this);

// convert image to bitmap
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(R.drawable.fried_chicken));

// Convert bitmap to byte
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
src.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] byte1 = baos.toByteArray();

// Convert byte to blob
Blob blob1 = new SerialBlob(byte1);  // Error here
```

I am trying to save the image into a database by converting it from a jpeg to blob

Even though I had imported `java.sql.Blob`, I cant seem to use `SerialBlob`. This can be seen in the image.

Any advice?

Comment: You use a blob for what exactly? Saving to database? Then the blob must be created by the driver, check the `Connection`'s methods for that. Also, please don't use images of your code. It makes your problem harder to search.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I am using Blob to save an image as a Blob and save it into a database. What do you mean by it must be created by the driver?

Comment: I've added the answer since there doesn't seem to be many different questions with answers about specifically writing using blobs. Also, pretty sure `String.valueOf(R.drawable.fried_chicken)` is not how you get the path to your image file. Check very carefully what that part returns, it might just be some integer.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov for the Connection, how do I know what to connect to?

Comment: You added the database to your app. Who better to know what you are supposed to connect with?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov is this connection connecting to a website or file directory?

Comment: It's a connection to a database. Which may or may not be on remote machine, but in case of android apps that's unlikely, you guys usually have sqlite or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Blobs are representation of binary arrays (which may be files) that your database engine know about.

This, typically, means that blobs are created by the driver, or added to the database's datafile registry some other way (but the latter is database-specific, can be unsupported by some databases, and unlikely to even be accessible for JDBC API).

For the first approach, there is an API since JDBC 3.0 (which is around Java 1.6):

```
import java.sql.Connection;

...

Bitmap src = <...create your bitmap...>
try (Connection conn = <...get connection from somewhere...>) {

   Blob b = conn.createBlob();

   OutputStream blobOut = b.setOutputStream(0); // 0 so you write to start of the blob
   src.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 100, blobOut);

   /* after all that you save blob by executing UPDATE or INSERT statements */
}
```